# How to convert scala dataframe to python data frame : Spark (Zeppelin)

Tags: scala, pandas, matplotlib, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to draw histogram for the spark data frame :

```
    val df2 = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3://testData/test.gz") 
    df2.show()

    val result1  = df2.withColumn("visited", explode($"visited")).cache  

    val query = result1.groupBy($"requestId", $"visited.placeName") 
                            .agg(avg($"visited.rating".cast("double")).alias("tmp")) 
                            .groupBy($"placeName").agg(avg($"tmp").alias("Average Rating")) 

    query.show()                        
    query.registerTempTable("query")

    %pyspark 

df = sqlContext.table("query").select()
df.printSchema
pdf = df.toPandas()

    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

    pdf.hist()
```

But I am getting error. I am using spark 1.5 Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ? I am converting the scala data frame to python pandas. Is that wrong ? How do I see histogram for the resulting value ? Do I need to change the full thing to python ?

Comment: @zero323 : I tried that given solution but still getting error : Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o101.table. : java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: query

Comment: Because you don't use Zeppelin correctly. You should use provided SQLContext.

Comment: @zero323 Care to explain ? I am new to this area . Trying to understand.

Comment: @zero323 R u mentioning this  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
 ?

Comment: I mean use `SparkContext` and `SQLContext` which are predefined in each shell as `sc` and `sqlContext`.

Comment: @zero323 I tried with predefined sc and sqlContext like you advised but still same error. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: To be honest I don't even want to guess. As long as you use Zeppelin as intended both solution work just fine have been tested.